# TableViewの下に一定の高さの空白を作りたい

Tags: swift, xcode

XcodeにてMaster-Detailの設定でプロジェクトを作成しました。
MasterのTableView下部に一定の高さの空白エリアを作りたいのですが、うまく作成できません。

TableViewの高さを `self.view.frame.height - 100` などにしたいのですが、これも適用されません。
`mainTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - 100))`

空白エリア作成目的でTextViewやTabbarなどのオブジェクトをTableView下部に配置しようとしても、うまく目的の位置に追加(配置)できません。

TableView配下にViewを追加しても上部に追加される（下部に移動不可）うえ、スクロールされてしまう。下部に追加した上で、スクロール時もスクロールされずに固定したい。

TableViewと同じ階層に配置もできない。

用途としては、広告などを表示することを考えています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Master-Detailのテンプレートで作られるTable Viewは、`UITableViewController`になっていて、これはTable Viewを画面全面に表示すること前提のものなので、ご希望の画面レイアウトを確実に動く方法で実現するのは難しそうです。「テンプレートで作られたTable Viewを一旦削除する」→「素の`UIViewController`を代わりに追加する」→「その上に`UITableView`を貼り付けて希望のレイアウトを実現する」→「セグエなどを元と同じように接続する」→「`MasterViewController`をこれに合わせて書き直す」なんて手順なら実現できそうですが、いかがでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。全画面前提なんですね。ご提案いただいた方法で改善できないか、検証して見たいと思います。